# A question about Dickey-Fuller Unit-Root Test

Tags: time-series, self-study, unit-root

I am reading Dickey-Fuller Unit-Root Test in *Time Series Analysis with Applications in R* by Cryer and Chan and have trouble understanding some discussion on equation (6.4.1).

So they took this example for illustration

> *Y<sub>t</sub> = αY<sub>t-1</sub>+X<sub>t</sub>* for *t*=1,2, ... where {X<sub>t</sub>} is assumed to be an *AR(k)* process: *X<sub>t</sub>* = *φ<sub>1</sub>X<sub>t-1</sub>* + ... + *φ<sub>k</sub>X<sub>t-k</sub>* + *e<sub>t</sub>*.

Under null hypothesis α=1. If let a = α-1, then

> 

*Y<sub>t</sub>* -*Y<sub>t-1</sub>*  = *(α-1)Y<sub>t-1</sub>* + *X<sub>t</sub>*

> 

= *aY<sub>t-1</sub>* + φ<sub>1</sub>X<sub>t-1</sub> + ... + *φ<sub>k</sub>X<sub>t-k</sub>* + *e<sub>t</sub>*

> 

= *aY<sub>t-1</sub>* + *φ<sub>1</sub>(Y<sub>t-1</sub>-Y<sub>t-2</sub>)*+...*φ<sub>k</sub>(Y<sub>t-k</sub>-Y<sub>t-k-1</sub>)* + *e<sub>t</sub>*     (6.4.1)

> 

with a=0 if null hypothesis is true.

I can understand till here. But then, they claimed the following:

> If {*Y<sub>t</sub>*} is stationary so that -1<α<1, then it can be verified that {*Y<sub>t</sub>*} still satisfies an equation similar to the equation above but with different coefficients; for example, *a* = (1-φ<sub>1</sub>- ... -φ<sub>k</sub>)(1-α) < 0. Indeed, {*Y<sub>t</sub>} is then an AR(k+1) procss whose AR characteristic equation is given by Φ(x)(1-αx)=0, where Φ(x)=1- *φ<sub>1</sub>x*-...-*φ<sub>k</sub>x<sup>k</sup>*.

and I cannot undertand. Why we have *a* = (1-φ<sub>1</sub>- ... -φ<sub>k</sub>)(1-α) < 0 ? Why is {Y<sub>t</sub>} an AR(k+1) process with the listed characteristic equation?